# Redirect page to 410 if match a specific Regex in .htacces

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I know this should probably go to SF but I think this community is way more active and it is probably a simple question for you so please be comprehensive :-)

So, this is my first time using .htaccess and I'm kind of freaking a bit I have a possible answer but I heard this could go wrong and I can't afford mass server problem.

The idea is that I want to redirect link ending by `/2/` or  `/3/` ... (number) to the `error410` page.

With your help I came up with this regex which is working well `^(.*?)\/(?!(?:404|410)$)\d+$` [Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/tD2sX0/5)

And if I get how this is working this is the right solution :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)\/(?!(?:404|410)$)\d+$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [G]
```

Do you think this will work or not ? I don't want to play the apprentice wizard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is quite complex. I suggest this :

```
# select URL ending with "/:numbers:/", and make a 410 redirection
RewriteRule \/[0-9]+\/$ - [L,R=410]

# Define what's the page for the 410 error
ErrorDocument 410 /error410
```

Comment: Yeah well, thank you, I'll end up using your solution since it mark my purpose :)